# Doctrine/Symfony2 Relationship Between 2 Entities over 2 Forms

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations

Current the following exists:

**Listing Entity**

```
class Listing {

/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="listing_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $title
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IntA\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade ={"delete"}, inversedBy="listings")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $user;



 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IntA\UploadBundle\Entity\Gallery", mappedBy="listing_gallery")     
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection $image
 */
private $image;
.
.
.
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="IntA\Bundle\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="listing_tag",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="listing_id", referencedColumnName="listing_id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection $tags
 */
protected $tags;
```

**Tag Entity** (Exists, but code not relevant for this problem)

**Gallery Entity**

```
class Gallery
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 

 * @var integer $gallery_id
 */
protected $gallery_id;
/**

 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IntA\Bundle\Entity\Listing", inversedBy="image")
   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="listing_id", referencedColumnName="listing_id")
 * @var integer 
 */
protected $listing_gallery;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
 * 
 * @var string $name;
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
 * 
 * @var string $description;
 */
protected $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_created")
 * 
 * @var DateTime $date_created
 */
protected $date_created;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_updated")
 * 
 * @var DateTime $date_updated
 */
protected $date_updated;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", length="255")
 * 
 * @var string $url;
 */    
public $url;



public $file = array();
```

**Gallery Controller**

```
public function uploadAction($id)
{
    $file = new Gallery();
    $images_form    = $this->createForm(new GalleryType(), $file); 
    $form_view = $images_form->createView();
    $form_view->getChild('file')->set('full_name', 'gallery[file][]');
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    #die(var_dump($request->files));
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $images_form->bindRequest($request);            

        $data = $images_form->getData();   
        #die(var_dump($images_form->getData()->getFile()));



            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($file);

            $related_listing = $em->getRepository('IntABundle:Listing')->find($id);
            $related_listing->setImage($data);

            foreach($images_form->getData()->getFile() AS $singleUploadedFile){

            $related_listing->setImage($singleUploadedFile);
            $em->persist($related_listing);

            }



            $em->flush();

            $uploadedFiles = $em->getRepository('IntABundle:Listing')->findAllImagesPerListing($id);



            return $this->render('UploadBundle:Gallery:view_uploaded.html.twig', array(
                                    'uploadedFiles'      => $uploadedFiles,                                        
                                ));
    }

    return $this->render('UploadBundle:Gallery:upload.html.twig', array(
        'images_form' => $form_view,
        'id' => $id,
    ));


}
```

Creating a listing (with image="") works without a problem on its form. I have created a separate form in which the user can upload a "Gallery" with multiple images inside of it. The images upload great, but I can't understand how to make a connection between the existing Listing object that the user just created and the images within the Gallery object that they would like to associate with the Listing object.

I'm not sure if my approach to the problem is right or if there exists a better approach. Right now I can create both objects, but not make the appropriate links between them. Is there example code out there to associate objects between two different forms? Perhaps I'm not looking the right places!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the owning and inverse sides in doctrine relationships:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

As far as I can see you need to be setting the relationship from the gallery as the many side should be the owner.

i.e

```
$gallery->setListing($listing);
```

rather than

```
$listing->setImage($gallery)
```

Because the inverse side of a relationship will not store the relation when you try and save it.

That would have your action looking like:

```
public function uploadAction($id)
{
    $file = new Gallery();
    $images_form = $this->createForm(new GalleryType(), $file);
    $form_view = $images_form->createView();
    $form_view->getChild('file')->set('full_name', 'gallery[file][]');
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $images_form->bindRequest($request);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $related_listing = $em->getRepository('IntABundle:Listing')->find($id);
        $file->setListingGallery($related_listing);
        $em->persist($file);
        $em->flush();

        $uploadedFiles = $em->getRepository('IntABundle:Listing')
            ->findAllImagesPerListing($id);



        return $this->render('UploadBundle:Gallery:view_uploaded.html.twig', array(
                'uploadedFiles' => $uploadedFiles,
            ));
    }

    return $this->render('UploadBundle:Gallery:upload.html.twig', array(
            'images_form' => $form_view,
            'id' => $id,
        ));
}
```

Comment: I understand the logic behind it now, especially after learning a bit more from the Dotrine docs. So in this case the Gallery entity is the owner as it should be the many side. It seems a bit un-intuative to have a Gallery owning the Listing.

Comment: Yeah its odd when you think about it logically but the docs do say that the relationship is for the ORM can be different from your domain model.  Glad it helped, did you manage to get the relationships working and saving correctly

Comment: In progress of editing the code to integrate the solution. Another quick question if you could help: setListingGallery in the Gallery entity should take a parameter of type Listing? I've only seen the many side of the setters where the type is simply ArrayCollection

Comment: yes it should take a parameter of type listing and just be `$this->listing = $listing`

Comment: Ok, got the association set between Gallery and Listing. Seems like it's only persisting the last uploaded file within the Gallery table (it's a multi-file upload with an ArrayCollection collecting the files).

I guess I need to loop through. Is it possible to add a setFile function that does a `$this->file[] = $file`? Somehow I have the feeling that it won't work as simple as that. So how to store multiple URLs to relate to each of the multiple files on a single post.
The upload creates one Gallery entity, uploads all files, but currently saves just the last file's url to the DB entry

Comment: you need to set up a file entity that is many files to one gallery or many files to many galleries, that way you can associate as many files as you want to the gallery. or you could store the files as a serialized array

Comment: So, Listing 1--1 Gallery 1/*--* File would be the relationship in the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12459/discussion-between-adam-and-luke)